# Struggling trying to create interface for Janrain-like services

Tags: design, php, interfaces

We are using Janrain in our app, but I have to create an interface to make this service easily replaced (because Janrain is so custom!, it does have common things in Oauth however)

However, I'm getting a hard time trying to achieve this.

What I don't want is to have, in my main `UserManager` service, a `JanrainClientInterface`, it should be neutral.

We need to use both Entity and Access APIs from Janrain:

```
interface OauthProviderInterface {

    public function getAccessToken(array $params);

    public function getAuthorizationCode(array $params);

    public function getCreationToken(array $params);

    public function getVerificationCode(array $params);

    public function useVerificationCode($verificationCode);

    public function authenticate(array $params);

    public function linkAccount(array $params);

    public function register(array $params); // registerNative in janrain API

    public function registerNativeTraditional(array $params);

    public function token(array $params);

    public function sendVerificationEmail(array $params);

    public function sendPasswordRecoveryEmail(array $params);
}

interface AuthenticationProviderInterface {

    public function authenticate($username, $password); // AuthNativeTraditional in Janrain API
}
```

These are more or less the API calls I will be using. I wonder if it makes sense what I'm trying to do, and how could I approach this.

Comment: what language is this, PHP?

Comment: @gnat yes it is PHP

Comment: You should as this on StackOverflow... You'll get more responses.

Comment: @visc: It would have to be a better question than this.  In its present form, it would be off-topic there.

Comment: I'm counting 12 functions in one interface. Are you telling me you have one object that uses every one of them? If not I'm going to throw the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) at you. If you do, well, do know what a [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) is?

Comment: Hello @CandiedOrange, Finally I split those into smaller interfaces, OauthProviderInterface, AuthenticationProviderInterface, UserEmailerInterface and UserProviderInterface. The problem is not that I did that, the problem is that Janrain offers an API with all those methods, but I would like to make the interface agnostic to the provider so I could easily replace it if needed, instead of tightly coupling my app to JanrainClientInterface. I ended with a lot more interfaces and proxy services, but maybe, maybe it is right.

Comment: Sounds like you figured it how. You could probably answer your own question.

Comment: @CandiedOrange you are right, maybe it will help someone. I found out I had to do a lot of "indirection" (is it called like that?) to get some kind of good abstraction. I hope it will not be hard to understand for future developers

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I did good, but in the end I came up with this:

These are Janrain specific interfaces:

```
interface JanrainAuthenticationInterface {

    public function getAccessToken(array $params);

    public function getAuthorizationCode(array $params);

    public function getCreationToken(array $params);

    public function getVerificationCode(array $params);

    public function useVerificationCode($verificationCode);

    public function authNative(array $params);

    public function authNativeTraditional(array $params);

    public function linkAccount(array $params);

    public function registerNative(array $params);

    public function registerNativeTraditional(array $params);

    public function token(array $params);

    public function verifyEmailNative($params);

    public function forgotPasswordNative($params);
}

interface JanrainEntityInterface {

    public function count($entityType, $filter = '');

    public function create(array $params);

    public function bulkCreate(array $params);

    public function delete($uuid, array $params = []);

    public function deleteById($id, array $params = []);

    public function deleteByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);

    public function bulkDelete(array $params);

    public function find(array $params);

    public function purge($entityType, $commit = false);

    public function replace($uuid, array $params);

    public function replaceById($id, array $params);

    public function replaceByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);

    public function update($uuid, array $params);

    public function updateById($id, array $params);

    public function updateByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);
}


interface JanrainClientInterface extends JanrainEntityInterface, JanrainAuthenticationInterface {

    public function getCurrentLocale();
    public function setCurrentLocale($localeName);
    public function getLocales();
}
```

These are provider agnostic interfaces:

```
interface AuthenticationProviderInterface {

    public function authenticate($username, $password);
}


interface OauthProviderInterface {

    public function getAccessToken(array $params);

    public function getAuthorizationCode(array $params);

    public function getCreationToken(array $params);

    public function getVerificationCode(array $params);

    public function useVerificationCode($verificationCode);

    public function authenticate(array $params);

    public function linkAccount(array $params);

    public function register(array $params);

    public function registerNativeTraditional(array $params);

    public function token(array $params);

}

interface UserEmailerInterface {

    public function sendVerificationEmail($userId, array $extraParams = []);

    public function sendPasswordRecoveryEmail($userId, array $extraParams = []);
}

interface UserProviderInterface {

    public function count($entityType, $filter = '');

    public function create(array $params);

    public function bulkCreate(array $params);

    public function delete($uuid, array $params = []);

    public function deleteById($id, array $params = []);

    public function deleteByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);

    public function bulkDelete(array $params);

    public function find(array $params);

    public function purge($entityType, $commit = false);

    public function replace($uuid, array $params);

    public function replaceById($id, array $params);

    public function replaceByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);

    public function update($uuid, array $params);

    public function updateById($id, array $params);

    public function updateByAttribute($attributeKey, $attributeValue, array $params);
}
```

Then there are four Janrain services implementing the provider agnostic interfaces, for example:

```
class JanrainAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface {

    protected $janrainClient;

    public function __construct(JanrainClientInterface $janrainClient) {
        $this->janrainClient = $janrainClient;
    }

    public function authenticate($username, $password) {
        $params = [
            'signInEmailAddress' => $username,
            'currentPassword' => $password,
        ];
        return $this->janrainClient->authNativeTraditional($params);
    }
}
```

Then `JanrainClient` implementing `JanrainClientInterface`.

What I do is, is some kind of facade in the previous four services, relaying all calls to `JanrainClient`, with little logic.

Then, `UserManager` (Application Service, describing use cases) has a constructor where I inject those four services using provider agnostic interfaces:

```
class UserManager {

    /** @var UserProviderInterface */
    protected $userProvider;
    /** @var AuthenticationProviderInterface */
    protected $authenticationProvider;
    /** @var OauthProviderInterface */
    protected $oauthProvider;
    /** @var UserEmailerInterface */
    protected $userEmailer;

    /**
     * UserManager constructor.
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @param AuthenticationProviderInterface $authenticationProvider
     * @param OauthProviderInterface $oauthProvider
     * @param UserEmailerInterface $userEmailer
     */
    public function __construct(
        UserProviderInterface $userProvider,
        AuthenticationProviderInterface $authenticationProvider,
        OauthProviderInterface $oauthProvider,
        UserEmailerInterface $userEmailer
    ) {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
        $this->authenticationProvider = $authenticationProvider;
        $this->oauthProvider = $oauthProvider;
        $this->userEmailer = $userEmailer;
    }


    public function getUserBy($criteria) {
        // TODO: Implement
    }

    public function doTraditionalLogin($username, $password) {
        $response = $this->authenticationProvider->authenticate($username, $password);
        return $response;
    }
}
```